# How to split a vector by delimiter?

Tags: r

I have a vector of integer e.g. `c(1,2,0,3,4)` and I want 0 to be a delimiter and get `list(c(1,2), c(3,4))`. Is there any libary function I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No library function I know of but you can write your own:

```
split.vec <- function(vec, sep = 0) {
    is.sep <- vec == sep
    split(vec[!is.sep], cumsum(is.sep)[!is.sep])
}

split.vec(c(1,2,0,3,4), 0)
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $`1`
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: Nice. I was just testing something with `cumsum` too.

Comment: I think you can follow the same approach  and use `rle(is.sep!=0)` as the factor in `split` .  No coffee yet this AM so I haven't worked out the  details :-(