# how to split a vector by repeated occurrences of NAs

Tags: r

I would like to be able to define a function that will split a vector every time there are NAs (or other user defined separator) that have been repeated n times. In the form:

```
na.split = function(vec, n, sep = NA)
```

Where vector is the vector for splitting, n is the number of NAs that define the split and sep is the defined separator (by default NA).

For example with a vector such as this:

```
vec = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA 2)
```

The output would be a list of vectors such as this for n = 3:

```
vec1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5), vec2 = c(3, 2), vec3 = c(1, NA, NA, 2)
```

I have seen a similar question [How to split a vector by delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858262/how-to-split-a-vector-by-delimiter) which works for a singular instance but have not been able to find anything that works for repeated instances.

Comment: What are you expecting when `n=2` as a result?  do the consecutive `NA`s have to be exactly `2` or `>=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rle` from `base R`.  Create a `list` of `values` and `lengths` by applying `rle` on the logical vector.  Create another index ('i1') based on the `lengths` as 3 and `values` TRUE, `split` the 'vec' by creating a grouping variable based on 'i1' and then remove the NA elements at the end of each `list` element

```
rl <- rle(is.na(vec))
i1 <- rl$lengths==3 & rl$values

lst <- split(vec, rep(cumsum(c(TRUE, i1[-length(i1)])), rl$lengths)) 
lapply(lst, function(x) x[seq_len(tail(which(!is.na(x)), 1))])
#$`1`
#[1]  1  2 NA  4  5

#$`2`
#[1] 3 2

#$`3`
#[1]  1 NA NA  2
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2)
```