# R: read file with empty lines into different data.frames

Tags: r

I have obtained a table that has empty lines as *separators*.

Something like this

```
A    45
B    54
C    5

D    4
E    96
F    0
G    12

H    154
I    3
```

Is there a way to read this file into separate data.frames (one with A1, A2, A3 in the first column; one with B1, B2, B3, B4 in the first column; and one with C1, C2 in the first column)?

EDIT: I cannot tell by column 1 or column 2, where the entries belong to. So I cannot read the whole file and split it later.

Comment: Do you have any identifiers which could be used to trace to which block each row belongs?  If so, then I might try to just remove the empty lines, read then the entire thing in as a single data frame, and then split it inside R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858262/how-to-split-a-vector-by-delimiter) here on stack overflow, I made this. In this case, each "table" can have different number of columns as seen in the third table in my example.

I feel like it can be more efficient, so suggestions are welcome.

```
tab <- textConnection("A    45
B    54
C    5

D    4
E    96
F    0
G    12

H    154    354
I    3      489
")

tablines <- trimws(readLines(tab))

split.vec <- function(vec, sep = 0) {
  is.sep <- vec == sep
  split(vec[!is.sep], cumsum(is.sep)[!is.sep])
}

splittablines <- split.vec(tablines, sep = "")

lapply(splittablines, function(x) read.table(textConnection(paste(x, collapse = "\n"))))
```

results:

```
$`0`
V1 V2
1  A 45
2  B 54
3  C  5

$`1`
V1 V2
1  D  4
2  E 96
3  F  0
4  G 12

$`2`
V1  V2  V3
1  H 154 354
2  I   3 489
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file.
Then filter first column with `grepl`. That will give you separate files based on character in first column.

Comment: I edited the question, because I cannot tell based on the first or second column to which table the entries belong to.