# Count repeated elements (variable length) in a vector with R

Tags: r, vector

We know that a vector will contain repeated elements, and the pattern is

```
c("A","B","C","D")
```

But a subset of this pattern will be used, and it will always begin at A, and the order will be the same.

A simple example is

```
c("A","A","B","A","A","B","A","B","C","D")
```

And we can structure it in this way:

```
c("A",
"A","B",
"A",
"A","B",
"A","B","C","D")
```

I would like an output vector counting the length of the pattern:

```
c(1,2,1,2,4)
```

Comment: Try `rle(cumsum(x=="A"))$lengths`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell if you were interested in keeping the intermediate list of vectors. If not, @nicola's answer in the comments is the most elegant solution. If so, then I think adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858614/12586249) answer and then taking the lengths may be useful:

```r
inp <- c("A","A","B","A","A","B","A","B","C","D")

split.vec <- function(vec, sep = 0) {
    is.sep <- vec == sep
    split(vec, cumsum(is.sep))
}
out <- split.vec(inp, "A")
sapply(out, length)

# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 2 1 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This would would:

```
x1 <- c("A","A","B","A","A","B","A","B","C","D")
diff(c(which(x1 == "A"), length(x1)+1))
```